# How to use Azure application insight in Typescript

Tags: typescript, azure, appinsights

How to use Azure application insight in Typescript .The already available solutions are for Angular which isn't working for me.

I tried the solution for angular , it didn't work. i used a 3rd party tool as well. it didn't work.

Comment: please give more details about your issue and share your code what you have tried? and how you can integrate appinsights with typescript?

Answer (score 0):

> How to use Azure application insight in Typescript

I created a sample TypeScript application using the commands below.

```
npm init -y
npm install typescript --save-dev 
npx tsc --init
```

I have installed the required packages below:

```
npm install applicationinsights --save
npm install @types/applicationinsights --save-dev
```

Using the code below, configure Application Insights with the AppInsights instrumentation key.

**Code:**

```js
import * as appInsights from 'applicationinsights';

appInsights.setup('b607ca1b-7bd2-4682-b93d-a2d911cf03e9').start();

function trackEvent() {
  const client = appInsights.defaultClient;
  const telemetry = { name: 'Custom Event', properties: { key: 'value' } };
  client.trackEvent(telemetry);
  client.flush();

  console.log('Telemetry data sent - Event:', telemetry);
}

function trackTrace() {
  const client = appInsights.defaultClient;
  const message = 'This is a sample trace message.';
  client.trackTrace({ message });
  client.flush(); 

  console.log('Telemetry data sent - Trace:', message);
}

function trackMetric() {
  const client = appInsights.defaultClient;
  const metricName = 'Custom Metric';
  const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); 
  client.trackMetric({ name: metricName, value });
  client.flush(); 

  console.log('Telemetry data sent - Metric:', metricName, value);
}

trackEvent();
trackTrace();
trackMetric();
```

Use the following commands to run this TypeScript application.

```
npx tsc
node app.js
```

[image]

Using the information below, you can find the AppInsights Instrumentation key:

[image]

Using the above code, a custom event and trace message were successfully sent to Application Insights. See below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much , i was able to add this to me code.

Comment: I have a problem when i am using trackexception , it is failing in test cases , saying it is undefined, the trackexpection is being called from catch block .. and when i give consol.log() it works. but to identify it as exception how would i code it.